# Storing an array in core data swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, entities

I want to be able to store an array in a property called `items`. But core data does not store arrays for some reason.

How can I save a collection of data with a varying size in core data?

Please post code or a link to a tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over your temp array and store it in the following way:

```
for item in items {

   var newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName ("Item", 
         inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject

   newItem.setValue(item, forKey: "itemname")
}
```

If I understood your questions wrong, please correct me. Regards, Alex!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider creating another Entity, and using Relationship to link both Entities, to have your array of Items.

Answer (score 0):

Although storing an NSArray in Core Data is an architectural discussion,
sometimes you might have reasons not to store the objects in the array into a separate entity (over-normalisation, performance issues,..)

If you want to store an array of Foundation types, you can indicate the type of the attribute as `Transformable`. Core Data already has NSValueTransformers built in for every Foundation type as of iOS5.

If you have an array of custom NSObject, you might want to write a new NSValueTransformer subclass too handle the persistence of this custom object
More on NSValueTransformer can be found here: [NSValueTransformer](http://nshipster.com/nsvaluetransformer/)